# Usage of the subjunctive often?

Tags: subjunctive-mood

I have studied English extensively, yet I haven't seen various forms of the subjunctive ever, for example the third person singular and the negative form. They sound so wrong in my ears. Are they (the two forms of the subjunctive mentioned above) even used that often, or is it just me? Examples are:

- It is necessary that he **see** a doctor (contrasted with the indicative he sees).
- I recommend that they **not enter** the competition

The only ones that make sense to me are these three forms:

- I suggest that he **be** removed
- If he **were** rich....
- If I **were** rich...

For anyone who is wondering, here is a description of the subjunctive-mood, given in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_subjunctive):

"The subjunctive in English is used to form sentences that do not describe known objective facts. These include statements about one's state of mind, such as opinion, belief, purpose, intention, or desire"

[Though it must be added for balance that different grammarians use the term 'subjunctive' (as metalanguage in English) in conflicting ways, some grammarians rejecting the term as inapplicable when analysing English.]

Comment: Phrases like "...necessary that he see a doctor"; "recommend that they not enter"; ... are still very much in use in formal writing. OTOH, "... necessary that he sees a doctor" is just plain ungrammatical. Rather, today, you will find a rephrased structure.  instead.

Comment: Really? "It is necessary that he sees a doctor" sounds normal in my ears. Why is it ungrammatical when using the indicative? How does the meaning change?

Comment: They both sound good to me. The latter sentence to me though would be better without the relative pronoun. 'I recommend he not enter', sounds better to me.

Comment: @Deonyi The relative pronoun is indeed ommited often in informal speech, in contrary to literature. I haven't seen the subjunctive use of this form yet though.

Comment: @Kris Wrong. Pullum and Huddleston concede that the indicative is acceptable here, though they say their preference is for the 'mandative subjunctive'. This has all been covered here before.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth How does the indicative use change the meaning exactly?

Comment: @Stallmp Of course the relative pronoun is correct, but I was just saying in common speech it's usually omitted in such constructions, especially with the subjunctive.

Comment: @Deonyi That is exactly what I said haha, I just confirmed your thoughts to show you a possible explanation why the omission sounds better.

Comment: @Stallmp Oh, I see.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth My question focuses more on the usage of these specific forms, and why they sound weird to my ears (I am not a native speaker).

Comment: @Stallmp "It is necessary that he sees a doctor", "It is necessary that he see a doctor" and "It is necessary that he should see a doctor" say exactly the same thing. The first would be the most idiomatic of the three in conversation in the UK, while the second is probably the favoured form in the US. In formal writing in the UK, periphrastic _should_ is probably the favoured form. It certainly disambiguates the best (She insisted that I should go to the doctor's).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth That is interesting, because the meaning often changes. For example: - I insist that he is here (indicative, a forceful assertion of the fact that he is here) - I insist that he be here (subjunctive, a demand that the condition of his being here be fulfilled)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Not really, I am not interested in WHEN you should use the  tense. Because I do know that.

Comment: Really? "I insist that he is here at the meeting" or especially "I insist that he comes to the meeting" would be used far more often in the UK than "I insist that he be here at the meeting" or "I insist that he come to the meeting",  even when the meaning is "He'd better be here". Though this is probably not the case in the US.

Comment: The subjunctive is not a mood form but a clause type that uses the plain form of the verb ("He insisted that she **meet** her"). With the subjunctive, it is not a matter of modality, as you suggest, but one of bringing about the situation described in the content clause. Subjunctive clauses invoke the concept of 'compliance": in my example, he insisted on compliance. With only one exception, English expresses modality with the modal auxiliaries. The one exception is the 'irrealis' mood "were", (the ill-named past subjunctive for some), as in "If he were in love with her he'd marry  her".

Comment: Then why is there a tag called subjunctive-mood